# Postgresql: how to make full text search ignore certain tokens?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

is there a magic function or operator to ignore some tokens?

```
select to_tsvector('the quick. brown fox') @@ 'brown' -- returns true

select to_tsvector('the quick,brown fox') @@ 'brown' -- returns true

select to_tsvector('the quick.brown fox') @@ 'brown' -- returns false, should return true

select to_tsvector('the quick/brown fox') @@ 'brown' -- returns false, should return true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid that you are probably stuck. If you run your terms through ts_debug you will see that 'quick.brown' is parsed as a hostname and 'quick/brown' is parsed as filesystem path. The parser really isn't that clever sadly.

My only suggestion is that you preprocess your texts to convert these tokens to spaces. You could easily create a function in plpgsql to do that.

```
nicg=# select ts_debug('the quick.brown fox');
                              ts_debug
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 (asciiword,"Word, all ASCII",the,{english_stem},english_stem,{})
 (blank,"Space symbols"," ",{},,)
 (host,Host,quick.brown,{simple},simple,{quick.brown})
 (blank,"Space symbols"," ",{},,)
 (asciiword,"Word, all ASCII",fox,{english_stem},english_stem,{fox})
(5 rows)
```

As you can see from the above you don't get tokens for quick and brown